# Integral of Binomials

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, binomial-distribution

Is there a way to integrate a binomial coefficient? I've tried to put the following into Wolfram Alpha, but it doesn't return a result. I have a small suspicion that I'm going a bit over my head here, but does anyone know if this is even possible?

$$F(n) = \int_1^n \binom{n}{x} \,dx$$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For integer $n, x$ we have $${n \choose x} = \frac{n!}{x! (n - x)!} = \frac{\Gamma(n + 1)}{\Gamma(x + 1) \Gamma(n - x + 1)},$$
where $\Gamma$ is the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), and the rightmost expression is defined for most values of $n, x$, including for all values of $x$ in the interval $[1, n]$ of integration, when $n$ is a positive integer, so we can interpret $n \choose x$ as taking on that value.

If $n$ is a nonnegative integer, using the identity $\Gamma(z + 1) = z \Gamma(z)$ (cf. the factorial identity $n! = n (n - 1)!$) and the [Euler Reflection Formula](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Reflection_Formula),
$$\Gamma(1 - z) \Gamma(z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z} ,$$
gives that
$${n \choose x} = - \frac{n! \sin \pi (x + 1)}{\pi x (1 - x) \cdots (n - x)} .$$
Now, decomposing using the method of partial fractions lets us rewrite this expression as
$$\frac{\sin \pi (x + 1)}{\pi} \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} \frac{1}{k - x} ,$$
so that the original integral is
$$\int_1^n {n \choose x} \,dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{k = 0}^n (-1)^k {n \choose k} \int_1^n \frac{\sin \pi (x + 1) \,dx}{k - x}.$$

Now, substituting $u = k - x$ gives
$$\int_1^n \frac{\sin \pi (x + 1) \,dx}{k - x} = (-1)^{k + 1} \int_{k - 1}^{k - n} \frac{\sin \pi u}{u} \,du = (-1)^k [\operatorname{Si}(\pi (k - n)) - \operatorname{Si}(\pi (k - 1))],$$
where $\operatorname{Si}$ is the [sine integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral) function.
After reorganizing and applying a binomial identity we get
$$\boxed{\int_1^n {n \choose x} \,dx
= \frac{1}{\pi} \left[\left(\frac{1}{2} n (n + 1) - 1\right) \operatorname{Si}(\pi) + \sum_{j = 2}^n {{n + 1} \choose {j + 1}} \operatorname{Si}(\pi j) \right]}.$$

For example, for $n = 2$ we have
$$\int_1^2 {2 \choose x} \,dx = \frac{2 \operatorname{Si}(\pi) + \operatorname{Si}(2 \pi)}{\pi} = 1.63039\ldots,$$
and for $n = 3$,
$$\int_1^3 {3 \choose x} \,dx = \frac{5 \operatorname{Si}(\pi) + 4 \operatorname{Si}(2 \pi) + \operatorname{Si} (3 \pi)}{\pi} = 5.28618\ldots.$$

**Remark 1** It would be more symmetric to consider $\int_0^n {n \choose x} \,dx$, since $n \choose x$ and hence the integral is fixed under the change $x \mapsto n - x$, yielding the simpler formula $$\int_0^n {n \choose x} \,dx = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{j = 1}^n {n \choose j} \operatorname{Si}(\pi j) .$$ Notice that for $n = 1$ we get $\int_0^1 {1 \choose x} \,dx = 2 \operatorname{Si}(\pi)$, so twice the [Wilbraham-Gibbs constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Wilbraham-GibbsConstant.html), which arises in the [Gibbs phenomenon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon) in Fourier analysis and signal processing.

**Remark 2** Heuristically, we should expect that for large $n$, $\int_1^n {n \choose x} \,dx \approx \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k} = 2^n$. Already for $n = 16$ we have $F(n) = 65529.67158\ldots \approx 65536 = 2^{16}$, a relative error of $< 10^{-4}$.

Comment: Nice use of Euler reflection formula !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Cheers!

Comment: @TravisWillse: Interesting identity in remark 1. (+1) Minor correction: $7.31159\ldots \rightarrow 5.28618\ldots$

Comment: @user26872 Thanks for the correction. The old figure was for the integral of the same quantity over $[0, 3]$ and not $[1, 3]$.

Answer (score 8):

*This is not a proof but just an observation.*

When $n$ is large, it *seems* that
$$I_n=\int_1 ^n\frac{\Gamma (n+1)}{\Gamma (x+1) \Gamma (n-x+1)}\,dx \sim 2^n$$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
n & 2^n & \text{Round}[I_n] & \Delta_n \\
 10 & 1024 & 1019 & 5 \\
 20 & 1048576 & 1048569 & 7 \\
 30 & 1073741824 & 1073741814 & 10 \\
 40 & 1099511627776 & 1099511627764 & 12 \\
 50 & 1125899906842624 & 1125899906842610 & 14 \\
 60 & 1152921504606846976 & 1152921504606846960 & 16 \\
 70 & 1180591620717411303424 & 1180591620717411303406 & 18 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

The $\Delta_n$ form sequence $A163563$ in $OEIS$.

Comment: This makes sense considering the fact that the sum of all binomial coefficients for a given value of $n$ is $2^n$

Comment: @AndrewSotomayor. This has been my starting idea. Cheers :-)

Comment: Are those values for $n \ge 50$ accurate to so many digits?  For $27 \le n \le 40$ the difference between the integral and $2^n$ is less than $n/3$ and for $1 \le n \le 40$  less than or equal to $2n$

Comment: Could you double-check the numerical values for $I_n$? For $I_{70}$ for instance, I got something much closer to $2^{70}$.

Comment: @Gary. You are right : I was integrating from $0$ to $n$. Fixed. Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 5):

Using the Euler-Maclaurin formula, one finds
\begin{align*}
\int_1^n \binom{n}{x}dx 
&= \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n\binom{n}{i}}_{2^n-1}
- \underbrace{\frac{\binom{n}{n}+\binom{n}{1}}{2}}_{(1+n)/2}
- \underbrace{\frac{B_2}{2!}}_{(1/6)/2}
\left(
\left.\frac{d}{dx}\binom{n}{x}\right|_{x=n}
-\left.\frac{d}{dx}\binom{n}{x}\right|_{x=1}\right) + \mathrm{h.o.} \\
&= 2^n - 1 
-\frac{n+1}{2}
-\frac{1}{12}\left(
\underbrace{\binom{n}{n}(H_0-H_n)}_{1\cdot(0-H_n)}
- \underbrace{\binom{n}{1}(H_{n-1}-H_1)}_{n(H_n-1/n-1)}
\right)+\mathrm{h.o.} 
\end{align*}
where $H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i$ is the $n$th harmonic number and $B_2$ the second Bernoulli number.
Thus,
\begin{align*}
\int_1^n \binom{n}{x}dx 
&= \underbrace{2^n - \frac{1}{12}\left(19+7n-(n+1)H_n\right)}_{A_n}+\mathrm{h.o},
\end{align*}
We use that
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}\binom{n}{x} 
&= \binom{n}{x}(\psi(n+1-x)-\psi(1+x)) 
    & \textrm{$\psi$, digamma function} \\ 
&= \binom{n}{x}(H_{n-x}-H_x).
    &\textrm{integral $x$}
\end{align}
The value $A_n$ is a good approximation even for small $n$.
For example, the error for $n=10$ is about five parts in $10^5$.
It should be possible to show that the relative error decreases as a function of $n$.
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
n&\int_1^n\binom{n}{x}dx&A_n \\ \hline 
 2 & 1.630391411 & 1.625 \\
 3 & 5.286189266 & 5.277777778 \\
 4 & 12.95996138 & 12.95138889 \\
 5 & 28.64741529 & 28.64166667 \\
 6 & 60.34578753 & 60.34583333 \\
 7 & 124.0531664 & 124.0619048 \\
 8 & 251.7681597 & 251.7883929 \\
 9 & 507.489714 & 507.5241402 \\
 10 & 1019.217007 & 1019.268221 \\
 11 & 2042.949383 & 2043.019877 \\
 12 & 4090.686307 & 4090.778478 \\
 13 & 8186.427335 & 8186.543489 \\
 14 & 16378.17209 & 16378.31445 \\
 15 & 32761.92027 & 32762.09097 \\
 16 & 65529.67158 & 65529.8727 \\
 17 & 131065.4258 & 131065.6593 \\
 18 & 262137.1827 & 262137.4506 \\
 19 & 524280.9422 & 524281.2462 \\
 20 & 1048568.704 & 1048569.046 \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Should the lower limit be $0$ instead of $1$?

Comment: @DavidRaveh: Hmm. No. Can you explain why you think so? I can add some detail if needed.

Comment: My bad, I was following the intuition given by the other answers that for large $n$, $\int_1^n {n \choose x} \,dx \approx \sum_{k = 0}^n {n \choose k}$, that's where the confusion came from. Since you wrote a strict equality, I assumed that would require the lower limit be $0$.

Comment: @DavidRaveh: I have added some details.

Comment: I should be able to upvote a second time... :) I'll go through it thoroughly later, thanks.

Comment: @DavidRaveh: Glad to help.

Comment: The next term in the Euler–Maclaurin formula would give someting of order $H_n^3$ which is larger than the first correction term.

Comment: @Gary: I agree that this expansion appears to be asymptotic. I appreciate the close reading.